# div inside another div is not taking 100% of its size. It is letting some equal space on the right and left

Tags: html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I want to make a responsive website and when I used columns and rows in bootstrap, I am having this problem where the inner div will not take the whole space in another div. The div inside div having class profile_left will leave a space on each side.

Can you tell me what is wrong please?

Here is my code snippet:

```
div .profile_left{
border: 1px solid black;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}


div .profile_picture{
    padding:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

<div class="container">
    {% block content %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="profile_left col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12" style="width: 30%;">
                <div style="background-color: #01226c; text-align:center; padding:20px;">
                    <h3 style="color: white;"><strong>PROFILE</strong></h3>
                </div>
                <div style="background-color: white;">
                    <div class="profile_picture">
                        <figure>
                            <img src="{{ student.profile_picture.url }}">
                        </figure>

                        {% if student.profile_picture == 'default.png' %}  
                             <a href="">Add a picture</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
{% endblock content %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, based on the information you provided and your code snippet. I,m assuming that you want the inner div to inherit the entire space without any margin space. You are getting the space because of the Bootstrap class "col-xs-12", which is giving your inner div a padding of 15px on left and right.

Just set the padding to 0 in your div .profile_left CSS code

```
div .profile_left{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 padding: 0px;
}
```

If it doesn't work then use this

```
div .profile_left{
 border: 1px solid black;
 border-top-left-radius: 5px;
 border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 padding: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: @Usaama Thaaaanks a lot!! It worked ^_^. I did not understand then bootstrap 12 thing tho

Comment: You have added the bootstrap class "col-xs-12" in your div declaration. That class was giving that div padding on the left and right sides. Since you didn't set padding in your own CSS so the div was getting the padding that was available through the bootstrap style sheet.

Answer (score 2):

The inner div always takes full available width. Here a problem is the bootsrap. Bootstrap column (div with class col-) has some padding tyling. Hence, you have to remove this padding. Add `padding: 0;`

```css
.profile_left{
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thaaaanks! I already accepted the first answer. Upvoted for you :)))